# How do people handle failure in Roll For Shoes?

Tags: roll-for-shoes

One of the points that aren't very clear in Roll For Shoes is how to handle failure/HP type situations.  I am curious how other people have handled it and if they ran into any problems.

I was toying with using this:

- Players must make defensive skill checks when taking damage, with the ability to learn more advanced skills like ‘take a beating(2)’ or ‘Human pincushion(3)’ to help them avoid more damage.
- Players can fail as many times per encounter as the number of their highest skill.
- Players can revive fallen comrades with skill checks like ‘First aid(2)’ or ‘Brush it off(3)’

Comment: This is a fantastic thing to inquire into, but this isn't the place for it - you should probably look to a forum. Stack Exchange's Q&A engine focuses on problems that have one specific objectively best solution, whilst this is an invitation to discuss the various different systems people have used for a very large category of situations. A lot of them will be good! But [we discourage](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) discussion questions where very answer is equally valid, or which take the form of: "I use X for this, what do you use?" Forums are a great place for that though.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! If you don't want to ask this in a forum, the [chat] is always an option, too.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that might be the case.  It's hard to format questions for roll for shoes that meet that requirements due to how small the ruleset is and there being no 'official' ruleset.  I'll try to find a forum to ask in.

Comment: @Jon There's a similar form of question that can work well here: request a tried-and-tested solution for roll for shoes that meets certain criteria. Answers will be able to provide recommendations that are better or worse depending on how well they meet your criteria. I've asked a few questions of this form myself in Fate which involves a lot of this kind of creativity, e.g.: [on adding loot](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28181/), [on simulating a language barrier](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/26118/), [on dealing with extreme success](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27972/).